# pre-existing data, and entities

Tags: pages, database, templates, admin-menu

I'm new to WordPress, and I would like your opinion about the application I'm building. I have a database filled with a lot of data structured in a very nice and optimized entity design.

I'm creating a WordPress theme that makes use of this data. What I'm doing currently is creating a template per page like the following

```
Template Name: Example page
```

and then going to pages and creating a page and choosing the template associated with the .php file in which I'm using $wpdb to display my content.

I'm also using

```
add_menu_page()
```

to create menus in the dashboard.

I'm not using the POST table because I have a distinct ERD that I want to use. What do you think about this design. I feel like I'm not really leveraging WordPress, but what other options do I have if any?

Thank you, and I hope I explain the problem well. Please let me know if you need any clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is do you want to leverage Wordpress or do you want to use your custom data.

You can build fairly complex things in Wordpress even with a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields, make a bunch of custom post types that all have different custom fields(some of which can be other post objects, so a field of one post could be another post), and then have pages that list those custom post types. Not sure that this is enough for what you need, but this surely can be done.